# Error: Member not found: 'Material.maybeOf'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

Hi how to solve errors Error: Member not found: 'Material.maybeOf'. bool isMaterial = Material.maybeOf(context) != null; . I am using the flutter_date_pickers package: ^0.4.2 and I have checked that this is the latest version. The error occurred after I upgraded flutter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this process. Please add your flutter sdk version also.

set the package without version number

```
flutter_date_pickers:
```

then

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Still the same. The error still cannot be solved.